# Would extracting page metadata be a good use of multiple inheritance?

Tags: python, django, architecture, multiple-inheritance, mixins

I was wondering if I have a couple of models which both include fields like "meta_keywords" or "slug" which have to do with the web page the model instance will be displayed on, whether it would be advisable to break those page metadata elements out into their own class, say PageMeta, and have my other models subclass those via multiple inheritance?

Comment: I don't think you are giving enough information here. Can you give some examples?

Comment: I think some people have come to this question not realising it's Django specific. You've only mentioned that via a tag so it's easy to miss. Also I don't see a need for multiple inheritance in your example. It sounds like single inheritance would be enough unless there's other models you want to inherit from.

Comment: yeah really i meant using it as a mixin, which is why i used the term 'multiple inheritance'

Comment: A mixin with what though? At the moment it sounds like you just would do:
    model Something(PageMeta):
        ...

Answer (score 0):

General advice for a lightly-specified question:

Nontrivial multiple inheritance in Python requires Advanced Techniques to deal with the metaclass/metatype conflict.  Look over [this recipe](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/204197/) from the ActiveState archives and see if it looks like the kind of stuff you like:

### Extract from linked recipe:

> The simplest case where a metatype
>   conflict happens is the following.
>   Consider a class A with metaclass `M_A`
>   and a class B with an independent
>   metaclass `M_B`; suppose we derive C
>   from A and B. The question is: what is
>   the metaclass of C ? Is it `M_A` or `M_B`
>   ?
>
> The correct answer (see the book
>   "Putting metaclasses to work" for a
>   thoughtful discussion) is `M_C`, where
>   `M_C` is a metaclass that inherits from
>   `M_A` and `M_B`.
>
> However, Python is not that magic, and
>   it does not automatically create `M_C`.
>   Instead, it raises a TypeError,
>   warning the programmer of the possible
>   confusion.

Consequently, I recommend limiting your use of multiple inheritance in Python to the following cases:

1. You must, because your problem domain requires you to combine two separately-maintained single-inheritance libraries.
2. You have achieved such fluency with metatype and metaclass that you can write [recipe 204197](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/204197/) or its equivalent as easily and confidently as you can write a print statement.

Edit:

Here's Guido van Rossum in [An Introduction to Python](http://www.network-theory.co.uk/docs/pytut/MultipleInheritance.html):

> It is clear that indiscriminate use of
>   multiple inheritance is a maintenance
>   nightmare, given the reliance in
>   Python on conventions to avoid
>   accidental name conflicts.

Here he is again in [PEP 253](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0253/), which describes the ideas which were incorporated into Python, but not the implementation:

> Metatypes determine various *policies*
>   for types, such as what
>   happens when a type is called, how dynamic types are (whether a
>   type's **dict** can be modified after it is created), what the
>   method resolution order is, how instance attributes are looked
>   up, and so on.
>
> I'll argue that left-to-right depth-first is not the best
>   solution when you want to get the most use from multiple
>   inheritance.
>
> I'll argue that with multiple inheritance, the metatype of the
>   subtype must be a descendant of the metatypes of all base types.

This does *not* mean you shouldn't use multiple inheritance; I'm just warning you so you won't be suprised one day to find yourself slapping your forehead and exclaiming "D'oh! 
The metatype of one of my subtypes isn't a descendant of the metatypes of all its base types!  Don't you hate when that happens?"

Comment: is it that hard to use mixins in python?

Comment: @rick, the syntax for multiple inheritance in python is about as easy as it gets; whether it's hard or not ... well, I added four paragraphs from Guido van Rossum so you can get a sense of how the person on Earth who is most familiar with Python feels about multiple inheritance.

Comment: @rick, I hope there's a badge for asking a question which gets only downvoted answers.

Comment: Well, I've used mixins in Django and the boogie-man hasn't come for me ye........